# Why is the air above the Himalayas warmer than surrounding areas?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, climate, temperature, altitude

Looking at [earth.nullschool.net](https://earth.nullschool.net/#current/wind/isobaric/700hPa/overlay=temp/orthographic=84.04,30.85,447/loc=103.419,12.271) on `13.09.2021` you can see that the temperature above the Himalayas appear warmer than the surroundings (at 700 hPa):

[image]

At the surface it looks more like one would expect with lower temperatures than the surroundings:

[image]

I'm guessing the explanation is connected to the difference in elevation. And that for some altitudes, temperatures closer to the surface (but not *at* the surface) are higher.
Still, the same effect is not to be seen in other mountain areas in Europe and North America:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you check the 500 hPa map, you see distinct air movements from the west and southwest across the Himalaya range. So the slightly warmer air over the Tibetan plateau could be a result of adiabatic processes.

Comment: Heard of the Tibetan plateau and how it is warmer than simiar locations with comparable height ?

Comment: @gansub Thanks for the feedback! Would you care to quickly comment on why such questions are inappropriate for this sub? And no, I don't know why the Tibetan plateau is warmer. But I'd love to hear more about it!

Comment: @vestland First of all there is no forecast data available for 23rd September.

Comment: @gansub 23rd? I asked about 13th. Which is today.

Comment: @vestland No ! I changed the date from 23rd to 13th . Kindly check the edits.

Comment: @gansub Ah, sorry! Typo on my part. Thanks for the edit. The whole idea for writing up the date was to let people know that the images were from this particular date.

Comment: @vestland I withdrew my  downvote. Here is a quick answer. The Tibetan plateau is a elevated plateau. The 700 hPa surface at that location is pretty much at the ground and  not 3 kms above the surface. Given the elevated plateau there is a lot of sensible heating during the summer and this drives the monsoon circulation.

Comment: @gansub Thank you! Will this imply that the data available for the surface /  `Sfc` option are all adjusted for elevation? Sorry if that's a ridiculois question.

Comment: @vestland The 850 hPa and isobaric surfaces below  do intersect with the ground. Check my answer here on the Tibetan plateau - https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9246/easterly-jet-stream/9247#9247

Comment: Great read! Thanks!